# con- + personal noun

Tags: compounds

*Concittadino* = "fellow citizen"

But can "con-" be prepended to form other words, e.g.:

*Constudente* = "fellow student"
*Conparrocchiano* = "fellow parishioner"
etc.

?

Comment: There are also compatriota, compatrono, compossessore, condirettore, confratello, consocio. It's not a very productive prefix, I'd say. I'd exclude \*constudente because of phonotactics, it could be costudente (like *istante* comes from *instans*). Similarly, it should be *comparrocchiano*.

Comment: I agree with @egreg: there are some fixed words, but forming new ones is rare, mostly creative or humorous. For the rules governing co-, con- or com- see https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/con and https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/co-1/ .